# Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid statemnet - text table required when importing CSV data

Tags: java, hsqldb, hypersql

I am trying to import CSV data to HSSQL database using java and this SQL sentence:

```
statement.execute("set TABLE data_source source 'data.csv;ignore_first=true;fs=\\semi'");
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: invalid statemnet - text table required in statement [set TABLE data_source source 'data.csv;ignore_first=true;fs=\semi']
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.Application.main(Application.java:53)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid statemnet - text table required
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

P.S. using this in HSSQL client works fine:

```
set TABLE data_source source 'data.csv;ignore_first=true;fs=\semi'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash twice. The following code doesn't show any exceptions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:~/swdev/hsqldb/testdb", "SA", "");
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("create text TABLE data_source (id INTEGER)");
    statement.execute();
    statement.close();
    statement = connection.prepareCall("set TABLE data_source source 'data.csv;ignore_first=true;fs=\\\\semi'");
    statement.execute();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

Comment: @zygimantus edited my answer. What error do you get when running the code. Seems to work for me.

Comment: Which version of hsqldb have you used? I am using 2.3.4

Comment: The latest version, 2.3.4. What happens if you run the code?

Comment: Your code works fine for me somehow, I will add soon full code which fails to me.

Comment: Ahh, I see. You updated the question. You are trying to use it on a table which is not a TEXT table. See my create table statement.

Comment: Yes, my create table sentence needed 'text' word which I missed, now it is solved.